# Windows 7 64 bit dll registering vs Windows 8.1 64 bit dll registering

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-7, vb6

I have a 32bit compiled dll that contains vb6 code. On my previous os, which was windows 7 64bit, i was able to register and run this dll fine within my c# application. Now, running windows 8.1, when i try to register the same dll, it registers fine, however when i try to read the dll in my code, i get:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {D19A00C4-A7F9-4E14-A5E1-D060B7EB57F3} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

1. The 32bit dll (compiled as Interop.VB6Class) is used in a c# class
   that is build against x86.
2. I have tried both regasm from my 64bit folder and the 32bit folder, no luck
3. When i run Dependency Walker (a nice little application that checks if all your dll's dependencies are available and that your cpu version for the dll and its dependencies match), I still get the message "Modules with different CPU were found".

I have followed numerous links and advice, so if anyone can help me, I would accept you as my savior and forever call you king.

Comment: What utility do you use to register this VB6 dll --`regasm` or `regsvr32`? Also, don't use /i parameter just `C:\Windows\SysWow64\regsvr32.exe my.dll`

Comment: I have tried both regsvr32 and regasm. I don't use any parameters, just the cd command to the syswow64 folder

Comment: All this in `Command Prompt (Admin)`? That is elevated command prompt?

Comment: Yes, I have tried running as administrator and without, no success

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, but are you 100% sure that your project settings are correct. Your Platform Target should be x86 and the Prefer 32-bit check box should be ticked. Also are you running the Debug version or the release version?. You need to set your 32 bit settings for both environments. For the command line version print out the following to ensure your environment is correct.

```
Console.WriteLine("OS {0}, Process {1}", System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem, System.Environment.Is64BitProcess);
```

I know it's a long shot but it might help in finding the root cause of the problem.

Comment: The main application and all the dll's that it uses are build for 32bit as the client machines all run on 32 bit. I've settled for working on a normal windows 7 VM as 8.1 is giving all sorts of issues not only with visual studio but with eclipse as well. Thanks for the suggestion though.